# Single page with two Rewrite URL

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I am using rewrite URL in my application.

Presently i am using

```
<rewrite url="(?!.*?\b(?:iphonestatelist|iphonepropertytype)\b)~/([A-Za-z0-9-_ ]+)$" to="~/test.aspx?id=$1" />
```

its working fine,But my client wants to iclude google analytic

```
http://www.testsite.com/FX1670?utm_source=test&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=testsite
```

So now i want to implement two ways

1.Without Google analytic(Ex: http://www.testsite.com/FX1670)

2.With Google Analytic(Ex:  http://www.testsite.com/FX1670?utm_source=test&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=testsite)

Is there any possible to rewrite a single page("test.aspx") with two URL rewrites.
If not please help me how to do.

For google analytic URL rewrite i am using below code but its not working.

```
<rewrite url="(?!.*?\b(?:iphonestatelist|iphonepropertytype)\b)~/([A-Za-z0-9-_ ]+)$?utm_source=test&amp;utm_medium=link&amp;utm_campaign=tranzon" to="~/test.aspx?id=$1&amp;utm_source=test&amp;utm_medium=link&amp;utm_campaign=testsite" />
```

Plz do help me.

Comment: For the non-working google-analytics rewrite rule, try replacing the "?" character with "&" in the "url" value ("?utm_source" may need to be "&utm_source"). On the second note: is the method you're using to rewrite urls supposed to be standard asp.net feature?